# Programmin Vodoo? comment code is executed

Tags: php, html

```
// Get Id, Streamanbieter und StreamId
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `Id`,`Anbieter`,`StreamId`,`Online` FROM `streams`");

// Aktualisiere streams
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
    $id              = $row->Id;
    $anbieter        = $row->Anbieter;  
    $streamid        = $row->StreamId;
    $ison            = $row->Online;
    $set_online      = "UPDATE streams Set Online = '1' WHERE Id = $id";
    $set_offline     = "UPDATE streams Set Online = '0' WHERE Id = $id";
    //$set_onlinesince = "UPDATE streams SET Online_since = current_timestamp WHERE Id = $id AND Online_since = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'";
    $viewers         = get_viewers($streamid, $anbieter);
    $update_viewers  = "UPDATE streams Set Viewers = $viewers WHERE Id = $id";
    $set_zero        = "UPDATE streams Set Viewers = 0 WHERE Id = $id";
    $set_datezero    = "UPDATE streams Set Online_since = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' WHERE Id = $id";
    if(get_online($streamid, $anbieter) == true) {
        if($ison == 0) {
            //mysql_query($set_onlinesince);
        }
        mysql_query($set_online);
        mysql_query($update_viewers);   
    }
    else {
        mysql_query($set_offline);
        mysql_query($set_zero);
        mysql_query($set_datezero); 
    }
}
```

Check out the commented lines $set_onlinesince. I had the problem that `mysql_query($set_onlinesince)` was executed nearly all the time, so I made the `IF` clause and added an additional statement in the `Where` clause. It was executed most of times.
After that I made an echo into the `IF` clause. When I executed the file it didn't show the echo output but would execute the `mysql_query($set_onlinesince)`. Then I tried to outcomment the line and it still was executed. When I outcomment the variable with the query and it was still executed after page reload. That does freak me out.
I deleted the cache in my browser several times and also tried it in a different browser. There was no effect.
How can this happen???

Comment: It's pretty simple, commented code is never executed, the computer didn't do something wrong, you did.

Comment: Are your sure that the file you're editing is the same as the file you're executing ?

Comment: j_freyre, and: Even if the files are the same, does the machine have PHP opcode cacheing enabled? In my experience, opcode caches sometimes  miss updates. Refresh or disable the cache if that is the case.

Comment: ...and please use PDO instead of mysql_ functions, or at least use the damn mysql_escape_string()... Because one can store `"'; DROP TABLES; SELECT 1 WHERE 'a' LIKE '"` in any DB table cell too... Best not to trust even the data coming from the DB itself (personally had an issue about this!)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thanks guys for the advice, i will rewrite the code with either PDO or MySQLi. I already thought about prepared statements since they prevent SQL Injections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be possible in this scenario that the field is set to `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, which would update it automatically with one of the previous queries.

Comment: Ohh thanks :D
This was actually the problem, im happy now :P